# can System.currentTimeMillis make movement speed differ greatly?

Tags: java, multithreading, game-physics

Sometimes when I play my sidescroller, I move at the normal speed. However, other times my character moves very slow. The code never changes at all, so I think this currentTimeMillis method is at fault. Can anyone explain why I sometimes move very slowly and other times faster? Thanks.

```
public void run(){                              // run method for animation
        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();        
        while(animationDone == false){              
            jumpCycle();                    
            timeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
            sleepTime = 4 - timeDifference;         
            if(sleepTime < 0)       
                sleepTime = 2;              
            try{                        
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);        
            }           
            catch(Exception e){             
            }
            beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();    
        }
        isJumping = isFalling = animationDone = false;
    }
```

**Edit:** For anyone with the same problem, I ended up just using java.util.Timer and java.util.TimerTask to accomplish this with platform independent precision.

Comment: If you are sleeping the EDT you are certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: @John Vint
I'm not sleeping the EDT, I'm sleeping the animator thread created for the sole purpose of sleeping in this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inherent problem in your animation code is that you're relying on the passage of time to do the animation correctly. On any computer system this is impossible, due to thread scheduling.

The way computer games solve this problem is by changing the amount of animation done according to the amount of time that passed since the last draw. That way, regardless of your frame-rate, the animation speed will not change.

Comment: Thank you. I'll implement that.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems I see with your logic:

(1) you're assuming that the thread will sleep for precisely as long as you stipulate; in reality, this won't always happen: you could "ask" for 2 milliseconds, but have the thread return 10 milliseconds later; you really need to build the actual time slept into your logic, not assume that you will sleep for as long as specified; [ Have a look, for example, at the graph on this page showing the [difference in requested vs actual sleep](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml) time depending on system load ]

(2) you have an arbitrary condition where you set sleep to 2. Why? If the thread is effectively 'behind schedule', why sleep at all?

You might want to consider using the java.util.Timer class, which takes into account various quirks of the behaviour of Thread.sleep() for you.

Comment: 1. I didn't know that. What should I use that's more precise?
2. If the difference between when the method started and the current time is less than zero, something went wrong. As a kind of error handling, I set it to 2.

Comment: There's not really anything you can use that's more precise. But you need to measure and take into account the actual sleep time in your loop, not assume it was always what you asked for. So where you are calculating the sleep time of 4 - (time taken by algorithm), in reality this should be 4 - (time taken by algorithm) - (excess sleep from last round). But as I say, you might just want to use one of the built-in timer classes.

Comment: (P.S. I should say, it's not that there's nothing in the universe that's more accurate: a native application that needed precise timing, e.g. a music application, could use an interrupt handler; but Thread.sleep() is effectively what you have in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

From to [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) of System.currentTimeMillis():

> Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond,
>   the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating
>   system and may be larger. For example, many operating systems measure
>   time in units of tens of milliseconds.

So you cannot rely on it for small values and differences.

Likewise, [Thread.sleep](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease
>   execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the
>   precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.

What is a good way to pause a thread for very small amount of time -- which is what I think you are trying to do, I am afraid I have no idea.

Comment: Why would it make that large of a difference depending on when I run the program? And what do you recommend I use that's OS independent?
Edit: Thanks for the help, I'll look into a more precise way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.nanoTime()` instead, its resolution is finer.

Comment: The problem persists using nanoTime().